# How to connect the login and register page?

Tags: php

I am newbie in php so I need help. I have a page=start and a page=login. In page=login I have a link which navigates to page=register. But it doesn't do anything.

page=start

```
$page = 'home';
if (isset($_GET['page']) && file_exists('pages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php')) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

if (empty($_SESSION['Auth']) && $page != 'login') {
    header('location:index.php?page=login');

} elseif (!empty($_SESSION['Auth']) && $page == 'login') {
    header('location:index.php?page=home');
}
if (file_exists('actions/'.$page.'.php')) {
    include('actions/'.$page.'.php');
}
```

page=login

```
<form name="login" action="index.php?page=login&action=login" method="post">
        <p class="log">Hey! Log In</p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    <a href='index.php?page=register'>Register</a>
```

Comment: What are `page=start`and `page=login` exactly?

Comment: show all of your PHP code. we can't really help much since we don't know what is suppose to do what.

Comment: So what happens when the end user discovers that they can load any file in your filesystem? You aren't even screening `../` sequences.  Be more careful when processing user-supplied data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any more code, I'd guess that your redirect when there is no `$_SESSION['Auth']` is happening when you're trying to access the register page. You'll probably want to add an exception so that anyone can access it.

e.g.

```
$whiteListedPages = array('login', 'register');
if (empty($_SESSION['Auth']) && !in_array($page, $whitelistedPages)) {
    header('location:index.php?page=login');

}
```